# mathematical induction with exponent

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

$$\frac 13 + \frac 1{3^2} + \frac 1{3^3} + \dots + \frac 1{3^n} +  = \frac 12  \times \left( 1 - \frac{1}{3^n} \right)$$

Step 1 - $n=1$
$$\begin{align}
\frac 1 {3^1} & = \frac 1 2 \times \left( 1 - \frac 1 {3^1}   \right) \\
\frac 1 3     & = \frac 1 2 \times \left( 1 - \frac 1 3       \right) \\
\frac 1 3     & = \frac 1 2 \times \frac 2 3                          \\
\frac 1 3     & = \frac 1 3                                           \\
\end{align}$$

Step 2 - n$=k$
$$ \frac 13 + \frac 1{3^2} + \frac1 {3^3} + \dots + \frac 1 {3^k} = \frac 12 \times \left( 1 - \frac 1 {3^k} \right)$$

Step 3 - $n=k+1$

Having problems solving step 3.

Comment: What can you tell us about step 3?

Comment: In step 1, you state the equivalence from the beginning. You are trying to prove $$\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{1}{3 ^ 1})$$, so start with either side of that equation and transform it until you reach the other side, and that will prove equivalence. For example, $$\frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{1}{3 ^ 1}) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$.

Comment: Another valid way to do step 1 is to list the same equations you did, but in the opposite order. That is, start with a known truth, $\frac13=\frac13,$ and end with the equation you needed to prove.

Answer (score 1):

You must prove that $$\sum_1^k\frac{1}{3^i} + \frac{1}{3^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}\right).$$

Applying the assumption that $$\sum_1^k\frac{1}{3^i} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{3^k}\right)$$, you can get the result.

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis, we know that
$$
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{3^k}=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[1-\frac{1}{3^k}\bigg]
$$
Hence, by adding to both sides by $\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}$ we get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{3^k}+\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[1-\frac{1}{3^k}\bigg]+\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{3^k-1}{2\cdot 3^k}+\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{3^{k+1}-3+2}{2\cdot 3^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2\cdot 3^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[1-\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}\bigg]
\end{align}$$

Comment: The transformation from the first equivalence to the second is not clear. The truth from one line to the next should be clear and/or explained.

Comment: @ Kurtis Zimmerman I made an edit. Is this already okay?

Comment: Better -- I just edited and added a couple more intermediate steps. Still wasn't immediately obvious what was happening at each step.